# soap/wsdl test soapui

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, soap, soapui

I have tested my web services ( soap/wsdl) with SOAPui. but it show me that is in progress with the message : Loading definition Loading Definition from URL.
                   Loading Definition from URL.

and in 5minutes or plus it show me the error : error importing wsdl.

Is this because there a error in the Web services, or can be an other error ?? i am using ssl with mu url.

> can you help me please.

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the WSDL directly rather va URL (open the WSDL in a browser and save-as locally. [I dont have the reputation to make this a comment, as it should be]